# Finding the matrix of a linear transformation $T$ when $T$ maps a linear combination of basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's say you have a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ and we are given that a basis for $V$ is $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ so we want to find the matrix for $T$ by observing what it does to the basis elements. We are given this:

$T(v_1) = v_2$

$T(v_2) = -v_3$

$T(v_3) = -2v_1 + 2v_2$

$T(v_4) = 0$

Now, if it was something like

$T(v_1) = v_2$

$T(v_2) = -v_3$

$T(v_3) = -2v_1$

$T(v_4) = 0$

then I could easily put in the respective columns to get the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

But from the set of statements I was **given** I don't know how to form the matrix. Specifically, if $T(v_3) = -2v_1 + 2v_2$, what am I supposed to put in the third column for the matrix of $T$?

Comment: In the third column you need to put the vector of coordinates of $T(v_3)$ in the basis $\{v_1,...,v_4\}$. In your case the expansion of $T(v_3)$ is already given, the vector of coordinates is $(-2, 2, 0, 0)^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to label the bases on both sides of the matrix. So, in our setup, the bases are labeled as $$\begin{matrix}v_1\\v_2\\ v_3\\ v_4 \end{matrix}\overset{\mbox{$v_1$ $v_2$ $v_3$ $v_4$}}{\begin{bmatrix} &  &  & &\\ \\ \\ \\   \end{bmatrix}}$$ Where the entries in each column are the scalars needed to write the basis vector at the top of that column in terms of the basis vectors $v_1,\dots,v_4$. From the information that you are given, we see that $$T(v_1)=0v_1+1v_2+0v_3+0v_4$$ $$T(v_2)=0v_1+0v_2+-1v_3+0v_4$$ $$T(v_3)=-2v_1+2v_2+0v_3+0v_4$$ $$T(v_4)=0v_1+0v_2+0v_3+0v_4$$ This tells us all the entries that go in each column. The entries in the first column of the matrix above are the scalars needed to write $T(v_1)$ as a linear combination of the basis $v_1,\dots,v_4$. Thus, the first column would look like $$\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Where we put the scalars next to the basis vector given by our choice of ordering on the left side of the matrix. Writing out the whole matrix gives us $$\begin{bmatrix}0  & 0 & -2 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$